# Lua function range

Tags: lua

I got error if I do like this. What should I do?

```
local function one()
    local function two()
        local function three()
            callMe() -- got error here
        end
    end
end

local function callMe()
    print ("can't call :(")
end

callMe()
```

Comment: AFAIK, that code is not valid Lua: the functions `one`, `two` and `three` need `()` after them.

Comment: Sorry for my negligence. I was in a hurry while I was writing sample code here but that's not the real one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

locals have to be declared before used:

```
local callMe
local function one()
    local function two()
        local function three()
            callMe() -- got error here
        end
    end
end
function callMe()
    print ("can't call :(")
end
callMe()
```

Answer (score 4):

As well as the missing `()` for `one`, `two` and `three`, like Bart Kiers said, calling `three()` would error, as `callMe` is a local function outside of `three`'s scope, so it doesn't know that function.