# Lua: How to call a function prior to it being defined?

Tags: lua

What is the syntax to create the function, but then add it's implementation further down in code?

So roughly like this:

- Define function `doX`
- Call `doX`  (further down in the code)
- `doX` implemention  (i.e. all functions down at the bottom of the file)

Comment: You *cannot* call the function before it is defined, but perhaps Paul's answer meets your needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua function range problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394721/lua-function-range-problem)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> oh...so there's really no way to call funcName prior to having actually defined the function then? i.e. you still need to make sure defineIt is called before your first call to funcName itself?

I wanted to clarify this point, and I felt that an answer would be the better way than a comment.

Lua is a much simpler language than C or C++. It is built on some simple foundations, with some syntactic sugar to make parts of it easier to swallow.

There is no such thing as a "function definition" in Lua. Functions are first-class objects. They are *values* in Lua, just like the number 28 or the string literal `"foo"` are values. A "function definition" simply sets a value (namely, the function) into a variable. Variables can contain any kind of value, including a function value.

All a "function call" is is taking the value from a variable and attempting to call it. If that value is a function, then the function gets called with the given parameters. If that value is not a function (or a table/userdata with a `__call` metamethod), then you get a runtime error.

You can no more call a function that hasn't been set in a variable yet than you can do this:

```
local number = nil
local addition = number + 5
number = 20
```

And expect `addition` to have 25 in it. That's not going to happen. And thus, for the same reason, you can't do this:

```
local func = nil
func(50)
func = function() ... end
```

As Paul pointed out, you can call a function from within another function you define. But you cannot *execute* the function that calls it until you've filled in that variable with what it needs to contain.

Answer (score 15):

You only need to have a variable to reference. `local funcName` is sufficient for your purposes with one caveat. This will work:

```
local funcName
function callIt()
  print(funcName())
end
function defineIt()
  funcName = function() return "My Function" end
end
defineIt()
callIt()
```

As long as you define it (`defineIt`) before you call it (`callIt`), it should work as expected. You can't do something like this though (and this is the caveat):

```
local funcName
print(funcName())
funcName = function() return "My Function" end
```

You will get an error: `attempt to call local 'funcName' (a nil value)`.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the function definition in `defineIt`. It'll work just fune with `funcName = function()...` as a separate line. That is after all what `local function funcName()` does.

Comment: oh...so there's really no way to call funcName prior to having actually defined the function then? i.e. you still need to make sure defineIt is called before your first call to funcName itself?

Comment: @Greg: yes. If you really want to be able to call it before you "define" it, you can use `local funcName = function() end`, but it won't do anything useful (it won't throw runtime error either). You can then later set it to something else that does useful work for you.

Comment: @Nicol, right, I just wanted to emphasize the order of define/use operations.

Answer (score 8):

As others have written, you cannot call a function at runtime that has not been assigned prior to the call. You have to understand that:

```
function myFunc() print('Something') end
```

Is just a syntax sugar for this:

```
myFunc = function() print('Something') end
```

Now, it makes sense that this kind of code would not work the way you want it to:

```
print(greeter(io.read())) -- attempt to call global 'greeter' (a nil value)
function greeter(name) return 'Hello '..name end
```

When you use the `greeter` variable, its value is `nil`, because its value is set only on the next line.

But if you want to have your "main" program on the top and the functions at the bottom, there is simple way to achieve this: create a "main" function and call it as the last thing on the bottom. By the time the function is called, all the functions will be set to the corresponding global variables:

```
-- start of program, your main code at the top of source code
function main()
    local name = readName()
    local message = greeter(name)
    print(message)
end

-- define the functions below main, but main is not called yet,
-- so there will be no errors
function readName() io.write('Your name? '); return io.read() end
function greeter(name) return 'Hello, ' .. name end

-- call main here, all the functions have been assigned,
-- so this will run without any problems
main()
```

Comment: Good answer, a main() function is a pretty standard way of achieving this in Python