# Calling Functions Lua

Tags: lua

My problem is that I have a function that needs to be called before it is referenced. Another words, the code looks like:

```
doStuff()

local function doStuff()  end
```

and whenever I try to run it, it cannot reference the function doStuff(). My question is how can I call this function without moving the function above where it is called? So I don't want:

```
local function doStuff() end

doStuff()
```

since it will cause errors in other parts of my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [lua - how to call function from above it in code (prior to it being defined)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291203/lua-how-to-call-function-from-above-it-in-code-prior-to-it-being-defined)

Comment: Why can't you move the definition to be before the call, can you demonstrate the problem?

Comment: The reason is that this function is dependent upon a function between doStuff() and its definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> a function that needs to be called before it is referenced

You cannot. You need to solve this problem in a different way. The only situation you may need to do that is if you have two functions that recursively call each other. You can do this way:

```
local a
local function b()
  a()
end
a = function()
  b()
end
a()
```

This will go into infinite recursion, but you should get the idea. Another option is to use global variables, but you still won't be able to call a function before it's defined (by any means).