# Reference both earlier and later functions from other functions?

Tags: lua, function-declaration

I've got a Lua script that presents an interactive text menu for configuring the script before actually doing the work. There is a `main_menu()` function, which has options the user can select, each of which call a different `submenu()` function. Each of those different `submenu()` functions do their thing and then they go *back* to (they call) the `main_menu()` function. Finally, each function has a parameter of `settings` passed to it, which is a table of settings.

Things look like this:

```
local function submenu(settings)
    -- Get user input & change a settings{} table key accordingly
    main_menu(settings)
end

local function main_menu(settings)
    -- Present choices & get user input
    submenu(settings)
end

local settings={}
settings["foo"] = "bar"

main_menu(settings)
```

The problem is I'm getting `attempt to call nil` errors whenever (as far as I can tell) a function calls another function **that is defined later on in the script**. So if, as in the example above, I define `submenu()` and *then* `main_menu()`, `main_menu()` has no problem calling `submenu()`, but `submenu()` can't call `main_menu()`.

FWIW, this is being done in the ComputerCraft mod for Minecraft.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lua function range problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394721/lua-function-range-problem) and [How to call function from above it in code (prior to it being defined)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291203/lua-how-to-call-function-from-above-it-in-code-prior-to-it-being-defined)

Comment: Thanks for those links; I searched on this issue in Google before posting but wasn't able to find anything relevant, nor did I see anything like those threads in the thread suggestions that were presented while I was posting this one. Musta been using the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either do a `local function` with forward declaration like this:

```
local main_menu

local function submenu(settings)
    -- Get user input & change a settings{} table key accordingly
    main_menu(settings)
end

main_menu = function(settings)
    -- Present choices & get user input
    submenu(settings)
end
```

or do a global function declaration by removing `local` keywords:

```
function submenu(settings)
    -- Get user input & change a settings{} table key accordingly
    main_menu(settings)
end

function main_menu(settings)
    -- Present choices & get user input
    submenu(settings)
end
```

Comment: The top line of the first answer is invalid syntax; you need to use `local main_menu` rather than `local function main_menu` for forward declaration.

Comment: Hmm, ok. From what I read (only been dabbling in Lua for 2 days), it's best to stay away from globals if at all possible, so I'll try to implement the first solution you provided. The actual program has a whole mess of "submenu" functions; would there be anything intrinsically wrong with just declaring them all in one fell swoop up top (`local main_menu local submenu_1 local submenu_2`, etc) and only then defining them all?

Comment: @Sandwich In the context of computercraft, I see no problem with it ;)